# spring batch ItemReader

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have integrated Spring boot，Spring data jpa，Spring batch
When I run job and execute the query in step, the following error occurs：

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@e6aac6] for key [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@169a995{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=false; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.3.246:1521:chs; username=drp; validationQuery=null; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=30000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; }] bound to thread [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mozi.hip.service.service.impl.TaskServiceImpl.findTasks(TaskServiceImpl.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mozi.hip.service.batch.BatchReader.read(BatchReader.java:73) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mozi.hip.service.batch.BatchReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$665cc5e1.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at com.mozi.hip.service.batch.BatchReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$798954ce.read(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:157) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@e6aac6] for key [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@169a995{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=false; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.3.246:1521:chs; username=drp; validationQuery=null; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=30000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; }] bound to thread [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-4]
    at**org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:190) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:406) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Spring Batch.

You might want to check the Transaction Manager ISOLATION level you have set.